# iPhone/iPad application shows a blank screen on Ipad after upgrading to iOS 4.2

Tags: ios

Since I've upgraded my iPad to iOS 4.2, one of my universal applications shows a blank screen on iPad (on iPhone, it's OK).

The code creating the window for the iPad is:

```
firstVC = [[[PickerViewController alloc]             initWithNibName:@"PickerViewIpad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
ResultViewController* secondVC = [[[ResultViewController alloc]
            initWithNibName:@"ResultViewIpad" bundle:nil] autorelease];

PermanentSplitViewController* splitVC = [[PermanentSplitViewController alloc] init];
  splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVC, secondVC, nil];

[window addSubview:splitVC.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

PermanentSplitViewController is derived from UISplitViewController.

No fatal error at compilation.
No error at runtime.

Any idea how to solve this problem?